# Controlling running state during WebDeploy on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, msdeploy

When I try to publish my site using web deploy to Azure I get an error stating that one of my DLLs in the bin-Folder is still in use and cannot be replaced. So I want to stop the instance, deploy the site and restart it then.

I've found some informations on doing this using msdeploy.exe using the [recycleApp-provider](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ee522997(v=ws.10).aspx). I just can't figure out, how to use it in Azure CD scenarios because I have no control over msdeploy.exe here.

Comment: Do you have webjobs running in your site by any chance? Could they be using the dll?

Comment: @Zain: No. I know, that this is a DLL from the package SqlServer.DataTypes. So it is ok, that this dll is in use. I want the application to be shut down before the deployment starts.